# Which ChoiceBox-Event to choose?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I placed a ChoiceBox inside an fxml with JavaFX Scene Builder.

The FXML has a controller assigned to it.

My question is: Which event do I need to register if I want to know about changed values?

```
onInputMethodTextChanged="#languageSelectionModified"
```

this does not work with the following code

```
public void languageSelectionModified(Event event) {
    ChoiceBox<String> box = (ChoiceBox<String>) event.getSource();
    System.out.println(box.getValue());
}
```

and this only works for the initial click (i.e. opening the list, not when selecting an item):

```
onMouseClicked="#languageSelectionModified"
```

Although the Mouse-Events would never be a good choise because of situations where the touch or keyboard is the input-method, it still proves that the System.out can be reached.

I have absolutly no idea where those things are documentated (in the default Java-API they are not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a listener to your @FXML injected choicebox in your controller:

```
choicebox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(choiceboxSelectionChangeListener);
```

You can also bind to the selected item:

```
label.textProperty().bind(choicebox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty());
```

Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/3062859) of hooking up a listener in a controller for a ComboBox defined in FXML.  Logic for a ChoiceBox is pretty much identical.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This works well. So there is no way of doing it via the 'normal' FXML-events? If you could tell me where I might have been able to lookup the existing (and defineable) events for FXML-files, I mark your answer as answering my question.

Comment: No, you can't lookup events for this in FXML using JavaFX 2.0 to 2.2.

Comment: The selection model event triggers even when the value of the choicebox is set by code (in my case, I have one choice which populates a form of child choiceboxes) and I wish there was a clean way to distinguish "user driven changes" from code driven ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use FXML `onAction` attribute:

```
<ChoiceBox onAction="#languageSelectionModified" />
```